# MSSQL , How to let row updated only once

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sqltransaction

I have an table which has pre create rows. like

> **ID** **BilNo** **Field1** **Field2**

```
55 NULL blabldd blalala
56 48989 blalala blalala
```

For Example record 56 cannot be updated , becase of BilNo is not null. Now I have an two process(Query) or more than two which use trancation.Assume

```
UPDATE mytable set BilNo=95945 Where ID=55;
```

First process firstly lock the row for update  . Second process is wait for first process to finish update , than update again. By the way each process has their own BilNo. 
I want a scerino like this. İf first operation is being update for this row. Second operation must not be wait for first operation. Second operation cannot start and breking suddenly.

Comment: I do not understand completely what you're trying to achieve - but some of it sounds like you need to take a look at transactions

Comment: you wan't to Update Only Bill NO Which are NULL and how you will Assign Value to Bill No Which are NULL

Comment: While update process is contuning , other process cannot make update after a while

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for row-level locking?
https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233327&seqNum=6